# Can I run with Zombie Run with another person?

Tags: zombies-run

I am considering purchasing ZombieRun, but I have a question about it.
Sometimes, when I run, my girlfriend might join me. Is there a way to tell the app that we are running together? I am afraid I might have to sprint away at some point and that she will not .. so we'd become separated..
Does anyone know if such a feature exists ?

Comment: I know relationship advice isn't what you're looking for, but don't sprint away from your girlfriend, leaving her to be devoured by zombies.

Comment: @Studoku she seems to be thankful for your advice. Thanks, you made me laugh :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it, but you need to test if it is fun.

First thing is that Zombies, Run! is single player, not multiplayer. This means the best way to synchronize it for two players would be to connect speakers to one phone. Another way that may work is using the same playlist with shuffle turned **off** (but I never tested it).

For not running away from your girlfriend you can turn chases off. This way it is just running with a story and (in my opinion) a lot less fun. Also note that you do not lose if the zombies catch you. You just throw away some items, so base building gets a little slower. This means you can try to run away together with no real consequences if you fail to do so. The chases/sprints only last for about a minute and the speed you need is calculated from your current running speed. So it may not be too fast (you are probably running slower as a couple than on your own anyhow, so it is easier to run 20% faster than that for a minute). Additionally there should be no problem catching up.

So all in all it may be possible to use it with all features (maybe even with two phones). If it does not work for you, turn chases off and test again. And in any case: Please come back and report...

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no possible way for that to happen. I recommend leaving a review telling them that you would like that feature, and they might just add it.